# CDB Debugger makes my Qt program crashing instantly

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, compilation, qt-creator

I'm having troubles to make Qt creator compiling with MVSC compiler, so far I used to compile with MinGW and GDB Debugger which are native settings in Qt creator.
I think that the compilation (MVSC) works now, but that I'm having issues with the debugger which makes impossible to launch my application.
Every time I start to debug (F5), I have immediately the following message:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/984038errorMsgCDB.png
So I can't even open the program.
When I run (Ctrl + R) I see this in the output tab:
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/137526outputMsgCDB.png

I have installed Visual Studio 2013, the Debugging Tools for Windows, Windows SDK for Windows 7, and I'm working on a pc with Windows 7 64 bits.

My Build & Run settings in Qt creator look like that:

1. [image: Kits]
2. [image: Qt versions]
3. [image: Compilers]
4. [image: Debuggers]

Can you help me please? I'm struggling for many days to make it work with    MVSC because I have to used a third-party library which only supports MVSC compilers.

Comment: I had the same problem once... Programming without being able to debug, it's kind of ironic. I suppose it's a bug from Qt, because it seems to be better with Qt 5.5.1 (snapshot)